# NDSolve does not accept the boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear, boundary-conditions, coding-style

I am new at Mathematica and trying to solve a nonlinear PDE with the help of NDSolve.
H, the height of the current is a function of x and t. Based on the context I know the current has a parabolic shape.

I have 2 boundary conditions indicating the current's shape regarding the spatial variable x[0,1]:  H(1,0)= 0, Hx (0,t)=0.

Also, considering the temporal variable I have information about the height of the current at t=0.1, which is H= 0.74

Note: In my problem at t=0 there is a singularity, to deal with that t must be a small number other than zero

I wrote a code but it gives this error:

```
NDSolve::ndode: The equations {(h^(1,0))[x,t][0,t]==0} are not differential equations or 
initial conditions in the dependent variables {h}.
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
ClearAll[h, x, n, t]
 hx = D[h[x, t], x];
 ht = D[h[x, t], t];
 n = 2;
 sqrtTerm = Sqrt[1 + 4*n*Abs[hx]];
 pde = Sign[-hx]*1/2*D[h[x, t]*(sqrtTerm - 1), x] == -ht

 solution = 
 NDSolve[{Sign[-hx]*1/2*D[h[x, t]*(sqrtTerm - 1), x] == -ht, 
 h[x, 0.1] == 0.74, h[1, t] == 0, hx[0, t] == 0}, 
 h, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0.1, 10}]
```

Comment: "hx[0, t] == 0" is invalid code. I think you mean:  "(hx /. x -> 0) == 0"

Comment: @AWer Change "hx[0, t] == 0" to `Derivative[1, 0][h][0, t] == 0`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann, Thanks for your help. It solved now

Comment: @DanielHuber,  Thanks for your help.